Why are non-compact Hermitian symmetric spaces Stein spaces?
I look for a proof or at least a reference that Hermitian symmetric spaces are Stein spaces.
Because an irreducible Hermitian symmetric space is biholomorphic to a symmetric bounded domain, my question can also be expressed: Why are symmetric bounded domains Stein manifolds?

I think it just a consequence of their classification, see Helgason's book on symmetric spaces.

@MoisheKohan I have and I read Helgason's book. Unfortunately, I do not know a passage where he speaks about Stein manifolds. Does he use this concepts at all? Can you give me a precise reference? Thanks.

He should have discussed bounded domains.

@MoisheKohan. Yes, he did at p. 382ff in Chap. VIII, §7. But Helgason does not mention that bounded symmetric domains are Stein manifolds.

Strangely, the result is not Helgason's book. However, it is Hermann's theorem that for every Hermitian symmetric space $X$ of noncompact type, the image of (holomorphic) Harish-Chandra embedding of $X$ is a bounded convex domain $D_X\subset \mathbb C^n$. (This, of course, does not mean convexity of the image of a randomly chosen holomorphic embedding of $X$ in $\mathbb C^n$.)  See for instance page 286 in
Wolf, Joseph A., Fine structure of Hermitian symmetric spaces, In: Symmetric Spaces, Short Courses presented at Washington Univ., Pure Appl. Math. 8, 271-357 (1972). ZBL0257.32014.
for a clear treatment of Hermann's theorem. (You can find it in Joe Wolf's homepage here.)
Or, see Hermann's original paper (which I find more obscure):
Hermann, R., Geometric aspects of potential theory in the symmetric bounded domains. II, Math. Ann. 151, 143-149 (1963). ZBL0113.31003.
On the other hand, every bounded convex domain is holomorphically convex, hence, Stein. (See this question for an (unnecessarily complicated) proof of the fact that convexity implies holomorphic convexity.)
Thus, every Hermitian symmetric space of noncompact type is Stein.

@JoWehler: Please read my answer more carefully. By the way, I think when you say "noncompact Hermitian symmetric space" you assume that it has no compact factors, otherwise it will not be Stein.

@JoWehler: You still did not read my entire answer. I did not claim that a random holomorphic embedding will have convex image.

@JoWehler: Did you notice the reference to Hermann's convexity theorem in my answer? To repeat: I do not claim that a random bounded symmetric domain is convex. Hermann proved that the image of the Harish-Chandra embedding is convex. This is what is used in my answer.

Hermann's Convexity Theorem for the Harish-Chandra embedding was "the missing link" for me. Thanks for your explanation and references.
